# Android ClassLoader.loadClass JNI crash

Tags: android, crash, dalvik

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
  #00  pc 0x50f8e  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+89)
  #01  pc 0x59ee1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmLinearAlloc(Object*, unsigned int)+64)
  #02  pc 0x76a7b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #03  pc 0x76d77  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDefineClass(DvmDex*, char const*, Object*)+10)
  #04  pc 0x71583  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #05  pc 0x30c0c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #06  pc 0x343dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #07  pc 0x6d109  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+284)
  #08  pc 0x6d12d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
  #09  pc 0x76e69  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmFindClassNoInit(char const*, Object*)+108)
  #10  pc 0x6216b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #11  pc 0x62287  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #12  pc 0x65a6d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmVerifyCodeFlow(VerifierData*)+9760)
  #13  pc 0x68c91  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #14  pc 0x68ce3  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmVerifyClass(ClassObject*)+42)
  #15  pc 0x7704d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInitClass+116)
  #16  pc 0x742d1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #17  pc 0x30c0c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #18  pc 0x343dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #19  pc 0x6ce39  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+344)
  #20  pc 0x73b19  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #21  pc 0x30c0c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #22  pc 0x343dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #23  pc 0x6ce39  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+344)
  #24  pc 0x7431b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #25  pc 0x30c0c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #26  pc 0x343dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #27  pc 0x6d109  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+284)
  #28  pc 0x554af  /system/lib/libdvm.so (???)
  #29  pc 0x48c6b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
  #30  pc 0x4a81f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+394)
  #31  pc 0xf0d  /system/bin/app_process (???)
java.lang.Throwable: 
******* Java stack for JNI crash *******
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:195)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:315)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.lily.dexLoader.invokeStaticMethod(SourceFile:70)
    at com.lily.sdk.Web.<init>(SourceFile:77)
```

......

I can not reproduce this crash through my android app, but the monitor system reports this kind of crash many times.

It is not clear whether the dex is broken or the system dalvik is not stable.

Does anyone has any experience on this kind of loadClass crash?

Comment: That's not a crash, that's a deliberate abort. There should be a message in the logcat output indicating why the VM decided to die.

Comment: Thank you very much! And ‘abort’ means user's killing process? or something special? Moreover, how can I reproduce this kind of abort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the VM detects a serious problem, it will send diagnostics to the log, and abort. The VM in the version of Android you're using crashes itself by attempting to write to a read-only location (`0xdeadd00d`).

Looking at the stack trace, the last thing before `dvmAbort()` is `dvmLinearAlloc()`.  Looking at [a recent source file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-mr2-release/vm/LinearAlloc.cpp#265), the VM will abort in that function if it runs out of memory to allocate, or if it's unable to change the permissions on a page while in a special debug mode where pages are aggressively marked read-only.  It's almost certainly the former.  Looking at the logcat output would tell you for sure.

Assuming you're running out of memory, I'd guess you're running an old version of Android (<= gingerbread), where the "linear alloc" buffer was under-sized.  This region of memory is used to hold class meta-data, such as tables of methods and fields, but not the data itself (which is why it can be marked read-only to help hunt for memory trashers).  The only way to avoid the problem is to restructure the classes.

You can read more about the problem, and a solution deployed by Facebook engineers, in [this blog post](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-dalvik-patch-for-facebook-for-android/10151345597798920).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, and the device info is: "Device:  GT-I9103 android-15".  API level 15, so it means the memory is not so large to hold the dex?  By the way, the optimized dex file is as large as 4.2M(dex file is 1.3M). What is your opinion?

Comment: API 15 is 4.0.3 ("Ice Cream Sandwich"), which should not have this issue. According to the web, the GT-I9103 shipped with gingerbread but could be upgraded to 4.x. So I'm not sure why you're seeing this, unless there's something peculiar about that specific device. (Is it *only* that device?)

Comment: It is not only that device but many kinds: Huawei/T8833/hwt8833:4.0.4/HuaweiT8833/C01B411:user/ota-rel-keys,release-keys;  ZTE/P810N30/P810N30:4.3/JLS36C/20140829.115049:user/release-keys;  Coolpad/msm8660_surf/msm8660_surf:4.0.4/IMM76D/4.0.048.P4.121106.8950:user/release-keys;   Xiaomi/mione_plus/mione_plus:4.0.4/IMM76D/ICS22.0:user/release-keys; htccn_chs_cmcc/htc_primotd/primotd:4.0.3/IML74K/61230.1:user/release-keys...